# Pygame Window Not Responding

Tags: python, random, pygame

I am trying to make a game in Pygame where he objective is to start the game but the start button keeps moving whenever you touch it but the window will not respond. I am not finished with the code yet because I tested it and it didn't work. Here is my code so far:

```
import pygame
import random
import time
pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('BEST 3D PLATFORMER FPS GAME!')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)
display.fill((255,255,255))
def newposition()
    randx = random.randrange(100, 700)
    randy = random.randrange(100,500)
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pass
        if event.ty
    button = pygame.image.load('start.png')
    display.blit(button,(randx,randy))

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Please ask a question.  Also, working code to go along with it would be preferable.

Comment: You have an if statement that isn't properly finished. Also, you are infinite looping, saying `while True` with no wait or something to stop it is just going to crash the game.

Comment: find some tutorial and you will learn faster than asking on SO

Answer (score 1):

All comments inside code

```
import pygame
import random

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

WHITE = (255, 255, 255) # space after every `,`

FPS = 30

# --- classes --- (CamelCase names)

#empty

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

def new_position():
    x = random.randrange(100, 700) # space after every `,`
    y = random.randrange(100, 500) # space after every `,`
    return x, y # you have to return value

# --- main --- (lower_case names)

# - init -

pygame.init()

display = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600)) # space after every `,`

pygame.display.set_caption('BEST 3D PLATFORMER FPS GAME!')

# - objects -

# load only once - don't waste time to load million times in loop
button = pygame.image.load('start.png').convert_alpha()
button_rect = button.get_rect() # button size and position
button_rect.topleft = new_position() # set start position

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True

while running:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            #pass # it does nothing so you can't exit
            running = False # to exit `while running:`

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False # to exit `while running:`

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1: # left button
                 button_rect.topleft = new_position() # set new position

        # if event.ty # Syntax Error

    # - updates (without draws) -

    #empty

    # - draws (without updates) -

    # you have to use it inside loop
    display.fill(WHITE) # clear screeen before you draw elements in new place

    display.blit(button, button_rect)

    # you have to use it inside loop
    pygame.display.update() # you have to send buffer to monitor

    # - FPS -

    # you have to use it inside loop
    clock.tick(FPS) 

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

---

BTW: [simple template](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/pygame/__templates__/1__simple__.py) which you can use when you start new project.

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: This is very nice and elaborate and all, but he only asked to fix his code, not for you to write a new program for him. It _is_ very nice and generous, I agree, but you can't learn if everything is served to you (even if everything is well commented, like you have done). Sorry to criticize.

Comment: @C._ OP can learn how to create good code - because OP code is ugly. See PEP8.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, the fix is not straight forward. Here are my notes for python 3.6.1 and Pygame 1.9.3:

1) The event is unresponsive because there is no display generated for pygame, add a window display after pygame  initialization:

```
pygame.init()  # Initializes pygame
pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500)) # <- add this line. It generates a window of 500 width and 500 height
```

2) `pygame.event.get()` is a generates a list of event but not all event classes have .key method for example mouse motion. Thus, change all .key event handling codes such as

```
if event.key == pygame.K_q:
    stop = True
```

To

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
        stop = True
```

3) In some mac/python combinations even after the window is generated it doesn't focus / record keyboard events, this is a pygame issue and is fixed in a reimplementation of pygame using sdl2 (SDL is a cross-platform development library which provides low level access to keyboard, audio ,mouse etc). it can be installed by following the instructions here https://github.com/renpy/pygame_sdl2. One might need to install homebrew for it, which is another package manager for macOS. Instructions can be found here https://brew.sh/

4) after installing it using the instructions on github link you need to change all import pygame to import pygame_sdl2 as pygame

5) Voila! fixed ...

Answer (score 0):

You've got to load `button` outside the loop (it only needs to be done once.)

`button = pygame.image.load('start.png')`

Also, you have **defined** `newposition()`, but have not called it. Also, randx and randy would not be accessible from *outside* of the function, because the would be local to it.

So, change your function to this :

```
def newposition()
    randx = random.randrange(100, 700)
    randy = random.randrange(100,500)
    return randx, randy # Output the generated values
```

Then, before the loop :

```
rand_coords = newposition()
```

---

You simply forgot to *update* the pygame display with your modifications to it.

At the end of your loop, add `pygame.display.update()`, like this:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pass
        # if event.ty why is that here?

    display.blit(button,(rand_coords[0],rand_coords[1])) # Take our generated values
    pygame.display.update()
```

---

Final code :

```
import pygame
import random
import time

pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('BEST 3D PLATFORMER FPS GAME!') # Yeah, exactly :)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

display.fill((255,255,255))

def newposition()
    randx = random.randrange(100, 700)
    randy = random.randrange(100,500)
    return randx, randy # Output the generated values

rand_coords = newposition() # Get rand coords

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit() # Quit pygame if window in closed
        # if event.ty why is that here?

    clock.tick(60) # This needs to be in the loop 

    display.fill((255,255,255)) # You need to refill the screen with white every frame.
    display.blit(button,(rand_coords[0],rand_coords[1])) # Take our generated values
    pygame.display.update()
```